# THREE: Using worldmap.svg as material on sphere but there are too many pixels, how do i reduce them?

Tags: svg, three.js, 3d, pixel

I am using an svg so I can color single countries.
I know WebGL doesn't support svg, thats why it gets pixeled but the borderlines are pixeled too much, any idea how I can make it look better?

"THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture has been resized from (2000x1001) to (1024x512)"? 
The image gets cropped, is that the problem?

---

```
                var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                let scene = new THREE.Scene();

                var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

                var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5,32,32 );
                let texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("/img/world-background.5375a735.svg");
                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, color: "white"} );
                var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                sphere.rotation.y = 4.5;
                sphere.rotation.x = 0.5;

                scene.add( sphere );
```

---

[image: my sphere]

Comment: You might find [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-indexed-textures.html) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the resize, try to set the `minFilter` property of your texture to `THREE.LinearFilter`. This should noticeably improve the final texture resolution in your case. Alternatively, you can try to change your texture to POT (power-of-two) by default. That would mean using a resolution like 2048x1024.

`three.js R112`